# При завершении работы не выключается ноутбук Acer

Tags: администрирование, windows-10, windows-8

Товарищи, выручайте!

При завершении работы не выключается ноутбук Acer Aspire v3-771G - экран гаснет и ноут продолжает шуметь. Загуглил уже все, что можно - ничего не помогает: настройки электропитания поменял, драйвера обновил, неработающие устройства отключил, биос по дефолту установил, даже ось еще одну поставил (была 10, поставил рядом 8.1), ошибок в "монитор и надежность" нет. На 8.1 левых программ и служб нет вообще.

Но при перезагрузке, ноут нормально вырубается, а потом в штатном режиме запускается.

Из последнего вмешательства в систему: через консоль указывал загрузочник для win10.

Comment: У меня в Asus такая же беда была - помогало отключение сети(wifi) перед отключением)

Comment: Возможно это как-то связано с WakeOnLan - фичей, позволяющей удалённо включить аппарат.

Comment: @vp_arth, попробовал отключить wifi, фраза "Завершение работы" теперь висит дольше, но результат такой же.

Comment: Сталкивался с таким. Труднорешаемо. Просто нажимаете на кнопку ВКЛ/ВЫКЛ на несколько секунд и выключаете ноут таким образом. Но стабильность работы такой жёсткий способ не влияет. Проблем с ноутами после такого грубого выключения не было.

Comment: Пробовал `shutdown -s -t 0`?